# Need to click twice on form submit (AJAX)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I created a form that does not need page refresh when submitted and includes validation. My problem is I have to click the submit button twice to send the form. I'm guessing the problem is related to:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
$('.mainform').submit(function(){
```

My problem is I just can't figure out a better way to do this. I've included the full JS below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('<i class="fa-check"></i><i class="fa-exclamation"></i>').appendTo($('.mainform section'));

    $(".mainform").validate({
        // Rules for form validation
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                required: true
            },

            lastname: {
                required: true
            },

            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },

            phone: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 10

            },

            services: {
                required: true

            },

            message: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 10
            },

            human: {
                required: true,
                range: [4, 4]
            }
        },

        // Messages for form validation
        messages: {
            firstname: {
                required: 'Please enter your first name'
            },

            lastname: {
                required: 'Please enter your last name'
            },

            email: {
                required: 'Please enter your email address',
                email: 'Please enter a VALID email address'
            },

            phone: {
                required: 'Please enter your phone number'
            },

            services: {
                required: 'Please enter the services you are looking for'
            },

            message: {
                required: 'Please enter your message'
            },

            human: {
                required: 'Please answer security question',
                range: 'That is incorrect'
            }
        },

        // Do not change code below
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.appendTo(element.parent());
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $('.mainform').submit(function(){

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'toAction.php',
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $("#success").show().fadeOut(15000); //=== Show Success Message==
                    },
                    error: function(data) {
                        $("#error").show().fadeOut(15000); //===Show Error Message====
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault(); //=== To Avoid Page Refresh and Fire the Event "Click"===
            });
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: remove this thing $('.mainform').submit(function(){}); you don't need to wrap this thing anymore. Just using $.ajax...

Comment: Mmm, a submit handler that attaches a submit handler!

Comment: Yes... I have some learning to do. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

In the submit handler, you should just use an ajax request to save the data - the `submitHandler` is called when the form is submitted so there is no need to register another submit handler. Also there is to prevent the default action you can just return `false` from the submit handler

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('<i class="fa-check"></i><i class="fa-exclamation"></i>').appendTo($('.mainform section'));

    $(".mainform").validate({
        // Rules for form validation
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                required: true
            },
            lastname: {
                required: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            phone: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 10

            },
            services: {
                required: true

            },
            message: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 10
            },
            human: {
                required: true,
                range: [4, 4]
            }
        },

        // Messages for form validation
        messages: {
            firstname: {
                required: 'Please enter your first name'
            },
            lastname: {
                required: 'Please enter your last name'
            },
            email: {
                required: 'Please enter your email address',
                email: 'Please enter a VALID email address'
            },
            phone: {
                required: 'Please enter your phone number'
            },
            services: {
                required: 'Please enter the services you are looking for'
            },
            message: {
                required: 'Please enter your message'
            },
            human: {
                required: 'Please answer security question',
                range: 'That is incorrect'
            }
        },
        // Do not change code below
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.appendTo(element.parent());
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'toAction.php',
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $("#success").show().fadeOut(15000); //=== Show Success Message==
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    $("#error").show().fadeOut(15000); //===Show Error Message====
                }
            });
            return false; //=== To Avoid Page Refresh and Fire the Event "Click"===
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That was driving me crazy. I have some learning to do. You're the man Arun!